# Is vapor-liquid equilibrium in contradiction with Pascal's law?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

When in a closed container a small amount of liquid is introduced then at a fixed temperature $T$ we will have a vapor-liquid equilibrium and the pressure of the vapor at that temperature is called vapor pressure. In order to derive the relation between vapor pressure and temperature we must equate their chemical potentials i.e.:

$$μ_l (T,p)=μ_g (T,p)$$

What I don't understand is how is it possible for two phases to have the same pressure. For example when we have in a closed container liquid water with its vapor in equilibrium, the pressure of vapor can be approximated by ideal gas law. The liquid will also exert a pressure in the walls of the container (which can be approximated by another equation of state). Will the pressure of the vapor equal the pressure of the liquid? Initially I thought that it won't because the  pressure that the liquid exerts is:

$$p_l=p+p_g$$

where $p$ is the pressure from the corresponding equation of state for the liquid and $p_g$ the extra pressure that is transferred due to Pascal's law. But in a vapor-liquid equilibrium and in general when a system reaches equilibrium $T,p,μ$ must be same everywhere in the system. Where I got it wrong?

**Edit**

After reading the comments I think I should add the following. In order to find the coexisting curve that is the set of points $(T,p)$ where the phases coexist we must equate their chemical potentials. My problem is where the pressure ,when we write $μ(T, p)$, refers. Is the total pressure of the container (from both liquid and vapor) or the vapor pressure? I am thinking it must be the pressure of the container which must be the same throught both phases (equilibrium). But if is this pressure then I can't understand how for example Clausius-Clapeyron can be derived (where the $p$ refers to vapor pressure). Is the pressure of the liquid (neglecting gravity) so small that we can approximate the total pressure with that of vapor?

Comment: Hydrostatic pressure (your $p_g$) equals zero at the surface level (or in other words, at zero depth). And if a vessel has a hole below the surface, well, then the things won't be in equilibrium, because water will rush out.

Comment: If there is additional gas, than it is the total gas pressure for the liquid versus partial pressure for vapour.

Comment: The $p_g$ pressure refers to pressure due to gas. I have neglected gravity. I am asking if the pressure from the gas is transmitted to the liquid so the liquid exerts its pressure (due to the equation of state) plus the pressure from the gas.

Comment: It is quite trivial question from mechanics. Gas exert the same pressure on liquid as liquid on gas. If it was not so, the phase boundary would be moving until they would be the same.